# Merging 2 active records from different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following two objects:

```
users = User.where(:first_name => 'Abhas')
employees  = Employee.where(:first_name  => 'Abhas')
```

Is it possible to combine the two relations to produce one `ActiveRecord::Relation` object containing both conditions?

Comment: Do you use STI for this classes?

Comment: No I don't. They have the same schema though, maybe I should use STI in future, but can't at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw function for join `users & employees` and then tried `users | employees` and it worked. Not sure if that is the correct way to do it though.

Comment: that'll return array of both records..is it what you meant?

Comment: But after fetting this array you will not be able to call scopes over these records as this is now converted to array, and we cannot call scopes on array

Comment: Actually I have to return this in the API call. Active record would be better though. This is my work around till I get the correct one. I am using `jbuilder` to return the calls. If you can suggest a better one, that would be really helpful @Md.FarhanMemon

Comment: I don't want to call scopes on the array. I'm concatenating at the last. Though just thinking that being able to sort will be helpful after the merge. Can we convert this back to a `ActiveRecord:Relation`?

Comment: are `user` and `Employee` associated in anyway?

Comment: No. But they have the exact same schema, I'm sure that's not what you are looking for though.

Comment: try the answer I posted

Answer (score 0):

You could join those two tables and then execute the query in the joined table containing both conditions

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

in your `employee.rb`

```
belongs_to :user, primary_key: :first_name
```

in your 'user.rb'

```
has_one :employee, primary_key: :first_name
```

Then you can call,

```
User.where(first_name: 'Abhas').includes(:employee)
```

Comment: You are saying even if the `users` and `employees` not connected in any way this is a work around for that? This may work in this case but when I want to join says `User.all` and `Employee.all` and get an active record relation, it might not work, no?

Comment: in that case, `User.joins(:employee)` should work, didn't test though

Comment: This returns all the `User` which has an employee with the same first name. Or if I try removing the `primary_key: :first_name` from the models, it doesn't work as desired either.

Comment: Actually I was looking for a more generalised solution. Say tomorrow I want to return a concatenation of 2 different models, in that case too it will be an issue. I'm trying too. Will post if I find something.